# Removing a target character from a string using sscanf

Tags: c, input, scanf

I've recently been learning about different conversion specifiers, but I am struggling to use one of the more complex conversion specifiers. The one in question being the bracket specifier (%[*set*]).

To my understanding, from what I've read, using %[*set*] where any string matching the sequence of characters in set (the scanset) is consumed and assigned, and using %[^*set*] has the opposite effect; in essence consuming and assigning any string that does not contain the sequence of characters in the scanset.

That's my understanding, albeit roughly explained. I was trying to use this specifier with sscanf to remove a specified character from a string using sscanf:

```
 sscanf(str_1, "%[^#]", str_2);
```

Suppose that str_1 contains "OH#989". My intention is to store this string in str_2, but removing the hash character in the process. However, `sscanf` stops reading at the hash character, storing only "OH" when I am intending to store "OH989".

Am I using the correct method in the wrong way, or am I using the wrong method altogether? How can I correctly remove/extract a specified character from a string using `sscanf`? I know this is possible to achieve with other functions and operators, but ideally I am hoping to use `sscanf`.

Comment: Exit the store at the time the characters that are not allowed to have emerged. So It is probably impossible in the `sscanf`(and `scanf`) alone.

Answer (score 0):

The scanset matches a sequence of (one or more) characters that either do or don't match the contents of the scanset brackets.  It stops when it comes across the first character that isn't in the scanset.  To get the two parts of your string, you'd need to use something like:

```
sscanf(str_1, "%[^#]#%[^#]", str_2, str_3);
```

We can negotiate on the second conversion specification; it might be that `%s` is sufficient, or some other scanset is appropriate.  But this would give you the 'before `#`' and 'after `#`' strings that could then be concatenated to give the desired result string.

Comment: Note that this `sscanf()` can return 3 different return values and the *before* and *after* strings cannot be empty.  All these special cases make the `sscanf()` approach error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if you *really* want to use `sscanf` for the purpose of removing a single target character, you could do this:

```
char str_2[strlen(str_1) + 1];
if (sscanf(str_1, "%[^#]", str_2) == 1) {
    size_t len = strlen(str_2);
    /* must verify if a '#' was found at all */
    if (str_1[len] != '\0') {
        strcpy(str_2 + len, str_1 + len + 1);
    }
} else {
    /* '#' is the first character */
    strcpy(str_2, str_1 + 1);
}
```

As you can see, `sscanf` is not the right tool for the job, because it has many quirks and shortcomings. A simple loop is more efficient and less error prone.  You could also parse `str_1` into 2 separate strings with `sscanf(str_1, "%[^#]#%[\001-\377]", str_2, str_3);` and deal with the 3 possible return values:

```
char str_2[strlen(str_1) + 1];
char str_3[strlen(str_1) + 1];
switch (sscanf(str_1, "%[^#]#%[\001-\377]", str_2, str_3)) {
  case 0:  /* empty string or initial '#' */
    strcpy(str_2, str_1 + (str_1[0] == '#'));
    break;
  case 1:  /* no '#' or no trailing part */
    break;
  case 2:  /* general case */
    strcat(str_2, str_3);
    break;
}
/* str_2 hold the result */
```

Comment: Thank you. Both of these methods are insightful. I previously hadn't fully understood how the bracket specifier handled the (anti-)scanset in question, but now Jonathan Leffler's solution makes perfect sense. The character has to be consumed one way or another, before continuing with reading. Also, seeing as there could be characters before and after the target character, I overlooked the fact that I needed to use two strings. The exercise seems to suggest that this is possible with one call of sscanf, but I can't see that being the case now. Thanks again.

Comment: Note: `sscanf("", "%[^#]#%[\001-\377]", str_2, str_3)` returns `EOF` a 4th possible return value.

Answer (score 0):

> Removing a target character from a string using sscanf

`sscanf()` is not the best tool for this task, see far below.

```
// Not elegant code
// Width limits omitted for brevity.
str_2[0] = '\0';
char *p = str_2;

// Test for the end of the string
while (*str_1) {
  int n;  // record stopping offset
  int cnt = sscanf(str_1, "%[^#]%n", p, &n);
  if (cnt == 0) {  // first character is a #
    str_1++;  // advance to next
  } else {
    str_1 += n;  // advance n characters
    p += n; 
  }
}
```

Simple loop:

Remove the needles from a haystack and save the hay in a bail.

```
char needle = '#';
assert(needle);
do {
  while (*haystack == needle) haystack++;
} while (*bail++ = *haystack++);
```

With the 2nd method, code could use `haystack = bail = str_1`